# How is the signal frequency measured in Atmega?

Tags: atmega

How is the signal frequency measured in Atmega? In particular, how is the signal frequency **(sinus)** measured in *Atmega8*?

Answer (score 1):

You need to read the signal using an ADC pin of the ATMega8, sample it at the desired rate, and apply a FFT algorithm to determine the sine wave frequency.

Another way might be explained here: http://www.atmel.com/Images/doc8365.pdf

Best regards,
Alex Tofan